# 2 Failed test with my strcmp function

Tags: c++, strcmp

The code below is in my header file:

```
int mystrcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) // strcmp function
{
    while(*s1 == *s2)
    {
        if(*s1 == '\0' || *s2 == '\0')
            break;

        s1++;
        s2++;
    }

    if(*s1 == '\0' && *s2 == '\0')
        return (0);
    else
        return (-1);
}
```

The problem is when I run it my main.cpp says it fails 2 test

Below is an excerpt from my main.cpp:

```
void testmystrcmp(void)
{
   int iResult;

   iResult = mystrcmp("Ruth", "Ruth");
   ASSURE(iResult == 0);

   iResult = mystrcmp("Gehrig", "Ruth");
   ASSURE(iResult < 0);

   iResult = mystrcmp("Ruth", "Gehrig");
   ASSURE(iResult > 0);  // right here mystrcmp fails the test

   iResult = mystrcmp("", "Ruth");
   ASSURE(iResult < 0);

   iResult = mystrcmp("Ruth", "");
   ASSURE(iResult > 0);

   iResult = mystrcmp("", "");
   ASSURE(iResult == 0); // it also fails the test here but why??
}
```

Note: I cannot change the .cpp file

I have been trying to fix this issue but do not know how.

Comment: It never actually compares whether one character is greater or less than the other. That's like the main part.

Comment: I'm wary of simply fixing your code, as I'm pretty sure this is a homework question. If you trace your execution you should be able to see exactly why the assertion is failing. Hint: it has to do with the return value from `mystrcmp`

Comment: Are you trying to compare only length, or trying to implement an actual strcmp-esque function? You never compare the individual letters if the latter. If they have unequal lengths, you also always return -1, which is not dependent on which one is longer.

Comment: So I need to separate the cases of return 1 for the first string since it is alphabetically bigger (after) the second string and return -1 otherwise.

Comment: @user2548316: Your comparison function never returns anything besides `0` or `-1`. How do you expect the result to ever become greater than `0`???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strcmp` is defined to return a positive value if the "first" string is greater than the "second" string, a zero value if they are equal and a negative value if the "first" is less than the "second" string. So if the strings are not equal, you should decide which one is greater and then return the appropriate value.

An easy way to achieve that is to return `*s1 - *s2` (which also returns 0 when they are equal, as a bonus).

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your `mystrcmp` function, I see no spot where you return a positive number, so the compare between `"Ruth"` and `"Gehrig`" will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

You only ever return `-1` or `0`. Read the assertions, why are they failing?

Also, on line 5, you only need to check *either* `*s1=='\0'` **or** `*s2=='\0'`, since you know they're equal due to the `while` condition.

Answer (score 0):

As other people said, strcmp is supposed to return positive and negative numbers.

Try this instead:

```
int mystrcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2){
    for(;*s1 && *s2 && (*s1 == *s2); s1++, s2++){}
    return *s1 - *s2;
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why did you use a for loop instead of a while loop?

Comment: @Joe: Because it is shorter. `while` is better suitable for situations when "counter"(control variable) changes in non-trivial fashion (`if (something){ i++; }else{ i = nextValue();}` or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... your mystrcmp function does not fail the second test.

http://ideone.com/ZcW02n

```
#include <iostream>

int mystrcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) // strcmp function
{
    while(*s1 == *s2)
    {
        if(*s1 == '\0' || *s2 == '\0')
            break;

        s1++;
        s2++;
    }

    if(*s1 == '\0' && *s2 == '\0')
        return (0);
    else
        return (-1);
}

int main() {
        std::cout << mystrcmp("","") << std::endl;
        return 0;
}

 output: 0
```